# Retrieved value from associative array is wrong?

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

I've been going through the "Bash Pocket Reference" book and I got to the section about associative arrays. Now, trying the example code in the book gives me unexpected answers:

```
istanev@inspiron5559:~$ data=([joe]=30 [mary]=25)
istanev@inspiron5559:~$ echo ${data[joe]}
25
istanev@inspiron5559:~$ echo ${data[mary]}
25
```

Isn't data[joe] supposed to return 30? Why is it returning 25 instead? My bash version is 4.3.46(1)-release.

Comment: Hmm, but I get `bash: declare: data: cannot convert indexed to associative array`. EDIT: Never mind, got it to work :) So I have to declare it before assigning it

Comment: `unset data; declare -A data=([joe]=30 [mary]=25)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bash process arrays as indexed arrays.
In such case indexes are evaluated as an Arithmetic Expression.

```
$ joe=3    mary=6
$ unset data
$ data=([joe]=111 [mary]=bbb)
$ declare -p data
declare -a data=([3]="111" [6]="bbb")
```

The output reveals several things:

- The array is indexed: the `-a` in the output.
- The array does contain two values.
- The indexes of the values match the numeric values of variables `joe` and `mary`.
- The values contained in the array may be strings.

That is so even if the indexes are quoted (even single quotes):

```
$ joe=3    mary=6
$ unset data
$ data=(["joe"]=111 ["mary"]=bbb)
$ declare -p data
declare -a data=([3]="111" [6]="bbb")
```

If the strings used as indexes have not been defined to contain a number, are anyway evaluated as an Arithmetic Expression that has zero value.

```
$ unset joe    ;    unset mary    ;    unset data
$ data=([joe]=111 [mary]=bbb)
$ declare -p data
declare -a data=([0]="bbb")
```

What happened is that `[joe]=111` evaluated to `[0]=111`, setting the array at index `0` to `111`. But then, `[mary]=bbb` evaluated to `[0]=bbb`, thus replacing the array value at index `0` to `bbb`.

To actually have an Associative array it has to be defined as so before its use.
It can not be changed while it contains data. With the array set as above:

```
$ declare -A data
bash: declare: data: cannot convert indexed to associative array
```

But clearing it, we can:

```
$ joe=3  ;  mary=6  ; unset data

$ declare -A data

$ data=([joe]=111 [mary]=bbb)
$ declare -p data
declare -A data=([joe]="111" [mary]="bbb" )
```

As you can see, it doesn't matter that the strings used as indexes are also valid variable names and that they contain a value. They are used as string indexes for the Associative array.

Answer (score 1):

Associative arrays need to be declared explicitly, with `typeset -A` or something equivalent (`declare -A` or `readonly -A` in bash). By default, an array is a “plain” array, with integer indices. Non-numeric indexes on integer-indexed arrays are interpreted as arithmetic expressions, and unset variable names in arithmetic expressions are silently interpreted as 0, so `data=([joe]=30 [mary]=25)` sets `data[0]=30`, then `data[0]=25`, and `${data[whatever]}` is element 0 which is `25`.

```
bash-4.3$ indexed=([a]=aye [b]=bee [x+1]=cee)
bash-4.3$ echo length=${#indexed[@]} a=${indexed[a]} b=${indexed[b]} x+1=${indexed[x+1]} 1=${indexed[1]}
length=2 a=bee b=bee x+1=cee 1=cee
bash-4.3$ typeset -A associative=([a]=aye [b]=bee [x+1]=cee)
bash-4.3$ echo length=${#associative[@]} a=${associative[a]} b=${associative[b]} x+1=${associative[x+1]} 1=${associative[1]}
length=3 a=aye b=bee x+1=cee 1=
```

Since `indexed` is an array with numeric indices, `indexed[a]` and `indexed[b]` are both `indexed[0]`, and `indexed[x+1]` is `indexed[1]`. With an associative array, what is inside the bracket parsed as a string (with the usual expansions as in double quotes, so you can write `${associative[$key]}`).

Comment: Sorry @Gilles, but "Non-numeric indexes on integer-indexed arrays are silently interpreted as 0" is not the whole truth. Whatever is inside the `[…]` is evaluated as an Arithmetic Expression. Yes, it may evaluate to 0, but …, may as well, not. Read my answer.